# Hide my updates from friend's Steam Activity pages?

Tags: steam

Back in August 2012, Valve rolled out some [community updates](http://steamcommunity.com/communitycontent), including the "Friend Activity" page, which amongst other things can list which achievements your friends have acquired, which games they've purchased, and community content they've submitted:

[image]

Is there a method to hide **my** activity from appearing on my **friends'** "Friend Activity" pages?

Comment: If they only care about your Steam activity, they're not your real friends.

Comment: @Studoku Probably the correct philosophical answer, but still would be nice to have a practical one

Comment: You may be able to do this by setting your profile to Private, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: A fine question, I've been wondering the same.  I don't mind my friends seeing certain things, but I don't want them to see what I've recently played.  You can stop some activity being visible by playing in Offline mode, but of course that leaves you somewhat limited.

Comment: @Keavon I was able to do some testing with a friend last night, and it seems like this is the case. However, events posted while your profile was public seem to stay public, while events posted while private seem to stay private.  If you'd like to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Mejwell You really deserve the credit for testing that, but I went ahead and posted it so others can find the answer more easily in the future. You get my +1 on the question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution, but you can hide your public activity by [setting your profile to private.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4113-YUDH-6401) Note that your previously posted activity may remain in your friends' feeds. (Thanks to OP for testing this.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to activity then by the top right of your screen. You'll see '' Friend Activity Settings ''

You cannot hide your Recent Activity counter (Hours past 2 weeks) I haven't found it.

Answer (score 1):

I was just digging into some settings within my Steam profile and identified how to do this.  Couldn't say when this feature was added, but it does seem to fit the bill for the question.

Navigate to your profile -> Edit Profile -> Privacy Settings -> My Profile -> Game Details

As per the description of that setting (highlighting mine):

> This category includes the list of all games on your Steam account, games you’ve wishlisted, **your achievements and your playtime**. This setting also controls whether you’re seen as "in-game" and the title of the game you are playing.

Setting this to private will also hide your currently active game from your friends, but it will also hide your achievements and playtime from their feeds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can hide your activity in "friends activity" "friends activity setting"

Comment: I have never heard of such options. Mind detailing where to find them?